# snake in a 5x5 grid

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for ideas to solve the following problem: [image]

Is there a systematic way to get a counting of the snakes? Thanks.

Comment: Brute force and cases doesn't seem too bad here for the $5\times 5$ case... It would appear that the only legal places that you can put a left if any exist would be on the third row and that in doing so it tells you almost everything there is to know about that particular snake except for how many lefts there are in sequence.  You should be able to argue then that there are $10$ snakes that used a left but no ups, $10$ snakes who used an up but no lefts by the same logic, and then there is the case of if both lefts and ups are used which I leave to you to count (*there aren't many*).

Comment: If no lefts nor ups are used, this is a classic counting problem which has an easy answer involving binomial coefficients.

Comment: Brute force is likely ideal for this particular case, but in general I would expect this problem to be 'hard' in the way that lattice animal problems tend to be.

Comment: no left no up would be 8C4=70 cases; only left no up has 10 cases; no left only up has 10 cases; what i'm not sure is having both left and ups - are there 2 of them or 4 of them? the description of the problem is somewhat ambiguous there

Comment: There are the  ones listed by user526427, then six of the type described by JMoravitz. I see $70+20+6=96$ in total.

Comment: After looking closer, I agree with six containing both lefts and ups.  `RDDLDDRRURRD`, `RDDLDDRRUURRDD`, `RRDDLLDDRRURRD` and their reflections.

Answer (score -2):

Considering the conditions provided in the problem,

*The minimum length of snake will always be 7 squares long*

Now, let's assume, the downward indicating arrow as $A$ and the sideward indicating arrow as $B$ .

Now, as each snake is 7- squares in length, there are two possibilities :

• There are four $A$s and three $B$s

• There are three $A$s and four $B$s

One of the conditions stated by the problem is :

> No four squares can share a single vertex

Hence, there can't be :

• Four adjacent $A$s in the first case.

• Four adjacent $B$s in the second case.

Thus, assuming a linear arrangement of the elements $A$ & $B$ , and the above conditions,

The combinations are as follows :

Case 1 :

$\frac{7!}{4! x 3!} - 4! $= 11

Exemplary case : $A$$A$$A$$B$$B$$B$$A$

Case 2 : 
$\frac{7!}{3! x 4!} - 4!$  = 11

Exemplary case : $A$$B$$A$$B$$B$$B$$A$

Hence, the cases of shortest snake : 22

Comment: The OP's example of a snake is already more than $7$ squares long. And even if you're constrained to moving right or down at each step, there are ${8\choose4}=70$ different snakes. So $22$ is much too small.

Comment: Further, your interpretation of the phrase "No four squares can share a single vertex" is apparently way off.  You interpreted this somehow as "you may not repeat the same move four times in a row" while the intended interpretation is "you may not perform the subsequence of consecutive moves `LDR` or `URD` or `RUL` or other similar sequences which result in a $2\times 2$ square of spaces all occupied by the snake."